# How to style table data on Ingenico iSC480 Payment Terminal?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, liferay

I am creating a POS system and I am using Ingenico iSC480 for signature capturing and Payments. I want to display my custom data (item Details) in table form. Data is showing but I am unable to style it because CSS does not work in it. Only some basic tags of html works. How can I do this?

```xml
<XLINKEMVREQUEST>
  <TRANSACTIONTYPE>PPDDISPLAYTEXT</TRANSACTIONTYPE>
  <TITLE>POS</TITLE>
  <TEXT> <HR>
    <TABLE>
      <TR><TH>ITEM CODE</TH><TH>DESCRIPTION</TH><TH>QUANTITY</TH><TH>UNIT PRICE</TH><TH>TOTAL</TH></TR>
      <TR><TD>096295121230</TD><TD>LDR VIT B-12</TD><TD>3</TD><TD>9.99</TD><TD>0.0</TD></TR>
      <TR><TD>300318694121</TD><TD>ROBITUSSIN PEDIATRIC COUGH</TD><TD>5</TD><TD>25.0</TD><TD>0.0</TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
    <FONT COLOR="BLACK">
      <DIV ALIGN="RIGHT">SUB TOTAL : 154.97</DIV>
      <DIV ALIGN="RIGHT">TAX : 13.18</DIV>
      <DIV ALIGN="RIGHT">TOTAL : 154.97</DIV></FONT></HR>
  </TEXT>
  <PPDXMLINPUT />
</XLINKEMVREQUEST>
```

[This is the result I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37s3g.jpg)

Comment: According to the manufacturer's FAQ quoted [here](http://github.e-sites.nl/ingenico.css/) CSS is supported using dynamic templates (whatever that means)

Comment: In the documentation the said that you can use ['ingenico.css`]( https://github.com/e-sites/ingenico.css) as a template. They said that they provide subtle and customizable CSS styles that will make it easier to cope with the payment view and can be installed in a breeze.

Comment: Hi @LarsBeck   I am using Edge Express API. It does not allow me to do this.

Comment: Hi @Teocci I am using Edge Express API. It does not allow me to do this.

Comment: Hi @LarsBeck I am using Edge Express API. It does not allow me to do this